# Why does Raspberry Pi 400 use white color (and not black) for its USB 2.0 port?

Tags: pi-4, usb, hardware, pi-400

On a quick look up, it seems the general trend is white for USB 1.0 and black for USB 2.0. I also glanced through the [USB 2.0 specification](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification) to try find anything relevant but it seems a bit overwhelming for me.

RPi 400 hardware specs do indicate that the port is USB 2.0 ([here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-400-unit/)). However, since RPi 400 is based on RPi 4 ([as mentioned here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-400/)), is there a reason to why RPi 400 uses white for its USB 2.0 port while RPi 4 uses black for the same?

[image: Rpi400]
[image: Rpi4]

Comment: Why do you care what colour it is?

Comment: the white color may have to do with the available current

Comment: @CoderMike I am curious where the mismatch is arising from. Does the USB spec not force on a color, hinting that it's not always a good idea to rely on the color when making judgement (extends for devices besides RPi), or if it could mean something else specific to RPi as jsotola suggested, or if it is simply an oversight by Raspberry Pi?

Comment: aesthetics could be in play

Comment: All idle speculation! The Pi4 pictured has Teal connectors which also differ.

Comment: So, the question is about USB spec, not the PI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors of USB ports are more of a convention than a hard requirement. They have been reused many times over (e.g. many phone chargers use [red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAzm.jpg) color which is now being repurposed for USB 3.2).

Black / white colors especially have been used interchangeably, more in relation with design than with USB spec: a device in a white box would tend to have white ports, wile a black device would naturally opt for black ports. I suppose the white keyboard of the Pi 400 may have influenced the port color choice as well.